# Anonymous slice lifetime

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
fn fun() {
    let mut vec = vec![];
    {
        let x: &[u8] = &[1, 2];
        vec.push(x); // why is the compiler happy?

        let y = [3, 4];
        let z: &[u8] = &y;
        vec.push(z); // ok compiler is not happy 
    }

    println!("{:?}", vec); // after commenting this line the compiler is happy again 
}
```

I understand why the compiler complains about `"borrowed value does not live long enough"` for `y` but why is it happy with `x`? `x` is a reference to a slice without a name -- when is this anonymous slice dropped and what is its lifetime?

After commenting the `println` everything compiles, I guess this is because the compiler understands that `vec` is not used anywhere so it does not care.

Comment: What is the expected type of `vec`?  I believe the compiler thinks it it `Vec<& 'static [u8; 2]>`.  Try explicitly setting its type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `x`, the compiler reasons that `&[1,2]` is borrowing an expression that could be written in a constant, so it does [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion) to `&'static [u8; 2]`:

> Promotion of a value expression to a `'static` slot occurs when the expression could be written in a constant, borrowed, and dereferencing that borrow where the expression was originally written, without changing the runtime behavior. That is, the promoted expression can be evaluated at compile-time and the resulting value does not contain interior mutability or destructors (these properties are determined based on the value where possible, e.g. `&None` always has the type `&'static Option<_>`, as it contains nothing disallowed).

The expression for `z`, which is `&y`, can not be written in a constant, because it is borrowing the variable `y`, so the same does not apply for `z`.